# Python calculator - input validation

Tags: python, validation, input

Hi all a Python newbie here, I just created the following simple program that asks for three inputs, checks if/waits until those inputs are numbers, and then prints out their sum.

My question is: How can I make my code more compact? E.g can I use only one block of code instead of three? Can I make the input-checking smarter?

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

```
print ("-ADD THREE NUMBERS-")

while True:
    a = input("Please enter a:")
    try:
        a = float(a)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("'a' must be a number.")

while True:
    b = input("Please enter b:")
    try:
        b = float(b)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("'b' must be a number.")

while True:
    c = input("Please enter c:")
    try:
        c = float(c)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("'c' must be a number.")

print(a+b+c)
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a list to save all "variables" ('a','b','c') that you want show to the user. 
So the code became compacter:

```
input_requested = ['a', 'b', 'c']
results = []

print ("-ADD THREE NUMBERS-")
for input in input_requested:
    while True:
        user_input = input("Please enter '{}':".format(input))
        try:
            results.append(float(user_input))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print ("'{}' must be a number.".format(input))

print(sum(i for i in results))
```

When the input is correct save it in a list, otherwise catch the exception like your code. 
Ate the end, in order to print the sum of all inputs, you can use

```
sum(i for i in results)
```

which loop on the list of inputs and sum directly the elements.